# Trouble adding OPTION to T-SQL Query syntax

Tags: c#, t-sql

for some reason I just can't get the syntax right on this for adding the OPTION

```
   Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Config.DbConnectionString);

    using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"  SELECT  t.customerID,
                                                                            t.Photo
                                                                    FROM SomeTable t
                                                                    WHERE t.PhotoID = (SELECT MAX(PhotoID) FROM SomeTable WHERE customerID = @{0} OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
                                                                    GROUP BY CustomerID ) ", "customerID")))
    {
        try
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@customerID", DbType.String, customerID);
```

Comment: it doesn't like the option syntax, says stuff like Incorect Syntax near the keyword FOR, etc.  Just typical syntax errors not liking how or where I'm placing that option.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` is available from [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(SQL.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You have the hint placed after the sub query, before the group by.

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT t.customerID,
       t.Photo
FROM SomeTable t
WHERE t.PhotoID = (
                     SELECT MAX(PhotoID) 
                     FROM SomeTable 
                     WHERE customerID = @{0}
                  )
GROUP BY CustomerID
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Your confusion might be the result of the fact that the hint has to do with parameter values, and so you thought you had to put it just after the parameter. But `OPTION` *always* introduces a [**query** hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190322.aspx). Maybe, keeping that in mind will help you to remember the correct syntax, i.e. that `OPTION` should always go at the end of the entire query.